# I need to assert all the key presses. Is there a way I can assert all of them in one test case. I need to assert all of them and get the text

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So basically currently im only assertting ALT but i do want to assert for all of them into one assert and one test case rather than creating multiple asserts. I have to use only one assert so how can i get the text from each one of them and assert them all into one

```
public void signUp() throws InterruptedException{
        

        Actions act =new Actions(driver);
        act.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
        act.sendKeys(Keys.SPACE).build().perform();
        act.sendKeys(Keys.ADD).build().perform();
        act.sendKeys(Keys.ALT).build().perform();
        
        
        System.out.println("Actions");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,15);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("result")));
        System.out.println("works");
        String test=driver.findElement(By.id("result")).getText();
        
        
        Assert.assertEquals(test, "You entered: ALT");
    
        
        
        
        }
```

Comment: yes in one test case write all Assert statement. Assert should be for steps so having multiple assert is not an issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to assert multiple conditions with a single assertion, however this your flow can not be asserted with single assertion since you performing several separate actions in a sequence, each of them can be validated according to the "result"  element content, but once you performed a new action the previous action result will be no more there.
If you were performing those actions on different elements you could validate all the test actions at once.
For example if there were 4 inputs and you sent texts to each of them you can assert that

```
Assert.assertTrue(input1.getText().contains(firstInputString) && input2.getText().contains(secondInputString) && input3.getText().contains(thirdInputString) && input4.getText().contains(forthInputString), "Some of cases failed");
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you want to the text of `driver.findElement(By.id("result"))` shows which button was pressed? If I understand your code correctly, I think you can do so like this:

```
public void signUp() throws InterruptedException{

    private String getResultText() {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,15);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("result")));
        System.out.println("works");
        String test=driver.findElement(By.id("result")).getText();
        return test;
    }

    Actions act =new Actions(driver);
    act.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
    String enterTest = getResultText();
    act.sendKeys(Keys.SPACE).build().perform();
    String spaceTest = getResultText();

    act.sendKeys(Keys.ADD).build().perform();
    String addTest = getResultText();

    act.sendKeys(Keys.ALT).build().perform();
    String altTest = getResultText();
    Assert.assertEquals([enterTest, spaceTest, addTest, altTest], ["You entered: ENTER", "You entered: SPACE", "You entered: ADD", "You entered: ALT"], "Your failure message");
```

Comment: the last assert line doesnt work but everything else is fine.